# traer información de una lista de Sharepoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Tengo este bloque de código en una aplicación de consola `c#`

```
public void getCotizaciones()
{
     List cotizacionGet = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Empleados");
     CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
     query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                "</Geq></Where></Query></View>";
     ListItemCollection ToDoCotizacio = cotizacionGet.GetItems(query);
     clientContext.Load(ToDoCotizacio);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

     foreach (var cot in ToDoCotizacio.ToList())
     {
          Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} ", cot.Id);
     }
}
```

Lo que estoy tratando de realizar es mostrar en consola la lista que se llama `Empleados`, pero no se como traer todos los datos de la lista.

Comment: ¿`ToDoCotizacio` tiene datos? la verdad no se porqué necesitas convertirlo en ".ToList()".

Comment: `ToDoCotizacio`  tiene los datos de  ViewXml, pero no se como hacer el query para que me traiga toda la información

Comment: Puedes usar [SPQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms457534(v=office.12).aspx) en lugar de CamlQuery. Mira esta [respuesta](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/15346/35471). Creo que sería mas fácil para ti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La CAML query no es correcta, el significado de esta consulta es:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
            </Geq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

*Todos los elementos tal que su campo ID es mayor a..* Y ni siquiera se especifica un valor o algo.

Si tu objetivo es simplemente traer todos los elementos, ingresa esta consulta:

```
<View>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Saludos